# Function of the に (光に透けて)?

Tags: particle-に

長い髪をゆったりと一つに纏めた少女である。光**に**透けて紫紺に輝く、色素の薄い髪。

Hi. What is the function of the に in bold? See through the light?
Thank you.

Comment: Something akin to "in the light, you could see through her thin, pale bluish-purple hair," I'd wager. The 光に denotes a place so to speak, i.e. in the light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [#7 in this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166083) says, it indicates cause of effect, i.e. how the light makes the hair transparent. (Since the verb is 透ける or 輝く, it can't be locative.)

Comment: Thank you. So does the に in 紫紺に輝く also indicate cause/reason?

Comment: @chinoalpha Nope, #8, the next one: "shine in amaranth"